# Git : Not under version control fatal error

Tags: git, file-rename

I am trying to rename a file via Torotoisegit -> rename option. The file is already under version control as it was checked-in in a previous commit. I am getting "fatal error: not under version control" error. Any idea what could be causing this error? I have also tried renaming the files via "git mv" option but even then I am getting the same error.

Comment: Are you on a different branch where that file does not exist? You can see what exists in the current commit's tree with `git ls-tree HEAD` (or just `git ls-tree @` in the latest versions of git).

Comment: I am working on a feature branch & the file is present in my local as well as in remote repository. I tried the above command and it returns the file name that I am trying to rename.

Comment: Are you able to rename it from the shell via `git mv oldname newname`? If so, then the problem would likely be in Tortoisegit.

Comment: I think the problem is with Tortoisegit. I tried renaming the files via mv command and its working fine. Thanks.